# wordpress site migration: sql database error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I am going to migrate my wordpress site to another host, than i need to upload all content and database. During upload old database to my new host, showing this message"

```html
Error
SQL query:

<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
    <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
<a href="tbl_sql.php?sql_query=SHOW+TABLE+STATUS+FROM+%60countryn_ews%60+LIKE+%27wp_posts%27&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=countryn_ews&amp;table=wp_posts&amp;token=10945ea2302a757ebabaa49f1abdd5f3"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Edit</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<code class="sql"><pre>
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `countryn_ews` LIKE 'wp_posts'
</pre></code>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.1%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-server.html&amp;token=10945ea2302a757ebabaa49f1abdd5f3" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
</p>
<code>
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
</code><br />
</div>


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
    <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL quer' at line 1
```

If I ignore the message, Then also show the site, but i can not login dashboard with my previous user id password. How I can i solve this problem?

My site run by wordpress 4.0.1

Comment: your sql query should be terminated by ;

Comment: Checkout the comments/solutions provided at the bottom section of this link : `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html` Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First check the database export was complete. If that's done right, open the sql file in a text editor and remove the html part at the bottom of that file which says 
`<div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>`